# Remove duplicates in DF and convert into a JSON obj in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df something like below

```
Name         Series
=============================
A             A1
B             B1
A             A2
A             A1
B             B2
```

I need to convert the series to a list which should be assigned to each Name like a dict or json obj as something like below

```
{
   "A": ["A1", "A2"],
   "B": ["B1", "B2"]
}
```

So far I have tried using groupby, but it just groups everything a separate dict

```
test = df.groupby("Series")[["Name"]].apply(lambda x: x)
```

The above code gives an output as a df like

```
         Series
Name
A     0   A1
      2   A2
      3   A1
B     1   B1
      4   B2
```

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to ensure having , then [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) as list:

```
out = df.drop_duplicates().groupby('Name')['Series'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

Or with [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
out = df.groupby('Name')['Series'].agg(lambda x: x.unique().tolist()).to_dict()
```

Output: `{'A': ['A1', 'A2'], 'B': ['B1', 'B2']}`

If you have other columns, ensure to only keep those of interest:

```
out = (df[['Name', 'Series']].drop_duplicates()
       .groupby('Name')['Series'].agg(list).to_dict()
      )
```

##### sorting the lists:

```
out = (df.groupby('Name')['Series']
         .agg(lambda x: sorted(x.unique().tolist())).to_dict()
      )
```

Example:

```
# input
  Name Series
0    A     Z1
1    B     B1
2    A     A2
3    A     Z1
4    B     B2

# output
{'A': ['A2', 'Z1'], 'B': ['B1', 'B2']}
```

Comment: Is there a way to sort each of the lists ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with aggregate list and last convert to dictionary by [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
out = df.drop_duplicates().groupby("Name")["Series"].agg(list).to_dict()
```

If there is multiple columns is possible specify columns for test duplicates:

```
out = (df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name','Series'])
         .groupby("Name")["Series"]
         .agg(list)
         .to_dict())
```

---

```
print (out)
{'A': ['A1', 'A2'], 'B': ['B1', 'B2']}
```

If need sort lists:

```
out = (df.drop_duplicates()
         .sort_values(['Name','Series'])
         .groupby("Name")["Series"]
         .agg(list) 
         .to_dict())
```